# Bove-Capretta method in Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type

As an exercice on defining general recursive functions in Coq, I'm trying to 
implement a list merge function using an ad-hoc predicate, the so-called Bove-Capretta method.

For this, I'm following the pattern in the example for the `log2` function on Chapter 15 of Bertot and Castéran. First, I have defined a domain predicate for 
merge as follows:

```
Inductive merge_acc : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
 | Merge1 : forall xs, merge_acc xs nil
 | Merge2 : forall ys, merge_acc nil ys 
 | Merge3 : forall x y xs ys,
      x <= y -> merge_acc xs (y :: ys) -> merge_acc (x :: xs) (y :: ys)
 | Merge4 : forall x y xs ys,
      x > y -> merge_acc (x :: xs) ys -> merge_acc (x :: xs) (y :: ys).
```

Next, I defined the relevant inversion lemmas for the recursive calls of `merge`:

```
 Ltac inv H := inversion H ; subst ; clear H.

 Lemma merge_acc_inv3
     : forall xs ys x y,
        merge_acc (x :: xs) (y :: ys) -> 
        x <= y -> 
        merge_acc xs (y :: ys).
 Proof.
    induction xs ; destruct ys ; intros x y H Hle ; inv H ; eauto ; try omega.
 Defined.

 Lemma merge_acc_inv4
    : forall xs ys x y, 
        merge_acc (x :: xs) (y :: ys) -> 
        x > y -> 
       merge_acc (x :: xs) ys.
 Proof.
   induction xs ; destruct ys ; intros x y H Hxy ; inv H ; eauto ; try omega.
 Defined.
```

After these definitions, I've tried the following implementation of `merge`:

```
 Fixpoint merge_bc 
     (xs ys : list nat)(H : merge_acc xs ys) {struct H}: list nat :=
     match xs, ys with
     | nil, ys => ys
     | xs , nil => xs
     | (x :: xs) , (y :: ys) =>
        match le_gt_dec x y with
        | left _ h1 => x :: merge_bc (merge_acc_inv3 xs ys x y H h1) 
        | right _ h2 => y :: merge_bc (x :: xs) ys (merge_acc_inv4 _ _ _ _ H h2)
        end 
     end.
```

But, I'm getting a error message that seems related to a lack of type refinement in pattern matching:

```
    The term "H" has type "merge_acc xs ys" while it is expected to have type
       "merge_acc (x :: xs0) (y :: ys0)".
```

Next, I tried to define `merge` using the `refine` tactic:

```
  Definition merge_bc : forall xs ys, merge_acc xs ys -> list nat.
     refine (fix merge_bc xs ys (H : merge_acc xs ys) {struct H}: list nat :=
        match xs as xs' return xs = xs' -> list nat with
        | nil => fun _ => ys
        | x :: xs => fun _ =>
          (match ys as ys' return ys = ys' -> list nat with
           | nil => fun _ => x :: xs
           | y :: ys => fun _ =>
             match le_gt_dec x y with
             | left _ Hle => x :: merge_bc xs (y :: ys) _
             | right _ Hgt => y :: merge_bc (x :: xs) ys _
             end
           end (eq_refl ys))
        end (eq_refl xs)).
     +
       subst.
       apply merge_acc_inv3 with (x := x).
       exact H. exact Hle.
    +
       subst.
       apply merge_acc_inv4 with (y := y).
       exact H.
       exact Hgt.
  Defined.
```

And Coq returns the following error message:

```
 Recursive call to merge_bc has principal argument equal to
    "eq_ind_r
        (fun xs1 : list nat => merge_acc xs1 ys -> merge_acc xs0 (y :: ys0))
        (fun H : merge_acc (x :: xs0) ys => ...
```

which I had simplified a bit. It seems that the recursion isn't been done on a
structurally smaller subterm of `merge_acc xs ys`.

My question is, what am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

The complete working example is at the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/0161c8eb88a02bc5a13ffe1cb992e569).

**EDIT**: Fixing the spelling of Castéran.

Comment: The correct spelling for Castéran has the accent on the e, not the a.

Comment: @Yves: Sorry for the misspelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the fact you're using a subterm of `H` is hidden by the needless complication you have put into the definitions of `merge_acc_inv3` and `merge_acc_inv4`. There is no need for `induction xs`.

Additionally, during the pattern-matching on `xs` and `ys` you're losing the connection with the `xs` and the `ys` in the type of `H`. So here is what I have:

- Inversion lemmas without `induction` and easier to use (cf. the use of equality constraints `xxs = x :: xs`)

```
  Lemma merge_acc_inv3
     : forall xs ys x y xxs yys,
        xxs = x :: xs -> yys = y :: ys ->
        merge_acc xxs yys ->
        x <= y ->
        merge_acc xs yys.
 Proof.
    intros xs ys x y xxs yys eqx eqy H Hle;
    subst; inv H ; eauto ; try omega.
 Defined.

 Lemma merge_acc_inv4
    : forall xs ys x y xxs yys,
      xxs = x :: xs -> yys = y :: ys ->
      merge_acc xxs yys ->
      x > y ->
     merge_acc xxs ys.
 Proof.
   intros xs ys x y xxs yys eqx eqy H Hxy ;
   subst ; inv H ; eauto ; try omega.
 Defined.
```

- A dependent pattern-match which retains the connection between what the match looks like and the original `xs` / `ys`:

```
 Fixpoint merge_bc
     (xs ys : list nat)(H : merge_acc xs ys) {struct H}: list nat :=
   (match xs as us, ys as vs return xs = us -> ys = vs -> list nat with
     | nil, ys => fun _ _ => ys
     | xs , nil => fun _ _ => xs
     | (x :: xs) , (y :: ys) =>
        match le_gt_dec x y with
        | left _ h1 => fun eqx eqy =>
            let H' := merge_acc_inv3 _ _ x y _ _ eqx eqy H h1
            in x :: merge_bc _ _ H'
        | right _ h2 => fun eqx eqy =>
            let H' := merge_acc_inv4 _ _ x y _ _ eqx eqy H h2
            in y :: merge_bc _ _ H'
        end 
     end) eq_refl eq_refl.
```